# R code that filters like the data viewer

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

Ok so I cannot figure this out for the life of me, I want to filter my data based on a partial string match. here is my data, I am just showing the column i want to filter, but there are more rows in the overall set.  I only want to show the rows that begin with "CAO"  --this is easily achievable in the viewer

dataviewer image:

[image: dataviewer image]

Basically I want the R "code" that would reproduce this exact result.  I have tried using grepl like so

```
filter(longdata, grepl("^CAO",longdata[,1]))
```

I have tried using subset

```
subset(longdata,longdata[,1]=="^CAO")
```

I have tried subset with grepl and no matter what I do I cant figure it out.  I am new to R so please try and explain it thoroughly.

Comment: If you read ?subset or any introduction to dplyr, you'll see that you can/should use column names instead of numbers there... Btw, yes, you want grepl, not `==`. Without a reproducible example, I don't know that anyone can help beyond that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250 for guidance.

Comment: Have you tried `subset(longdata, grepl("^CAO",longdata[,1]))`?

Comment: I was actully wondering about that too, so I used the tidyverse function "read_csv" so technically its a tibble.  the column name has a space in it, so would I reference it like this: 

  `filter(longdata, grepl("^CAO",Issue ID))`

or

    `filter(longdata, grepl("^CAO","Issue ID"))`

Comment: Rui Barradas, When I try that code a "+" appears, Is there something I am supposed to do after that?

Comment: No, that happens when you don't close a parenthesis, but everything seems right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of grepl wasn´t recognized in your first code

```
library(tidyverse) #in this case access to dplyr and to tibble´s data_frame() function which preserves the spaces in the column names
longdata <- data_frame(`Issue ID`=c("CAO-2017-20", "CAO-2017-20", "CAO-2017-20", "AO-2017-20", "CA-2017-20"))
longdata %>% filter(grepl("CAO", `Issue ID`)) #patern "^CAO" also works
```

`%>%` is a piping operator that passes the outcomes of the previous operations further, here it´s loaded by `dplyr`.

Basically what I did was to load the `tidyverse` set of packages (read more on tidyverse [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/)). Those ones of interest are `tibble` and `dplyr`.
Then I created a sample data frame with `tibble`´s function `data_frame()`
Then I applied an *adjusted* function that you suggested, namely

```
filter(longdata, grepl("^CAO",`Issue ID`))
```

which is the same in its piped form:

```
longdata %>% filter(grepl("CAO", `Issue ID`))
```

Comment: hey, thank you so much, this works perfectly, could you mind explaining what '%>%' means, and also is the single quotation how you reference a column name with a space in it?

Comment: Glad to help. Check the update. `dplyr` is extremely useful for data manipulation in R.